# django how to set request user in client test

Tags: python, django, testing

I am testing a view and my test looks like:

```
def test_profile(self, user_id):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username="myusername", password="password", email="abc@testmail.com")
    self.client.user = user

    print(user.id)

    request = self.client.get("/account/profile/{}/".format(user_id), follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(request.status_code, 200)
```

Here my profile view has a `login_required` decorator. How can I set `user` to `request.user`?

Comment: [`client.login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login)

Answer (score 17):

I was trying to do the same myself but found out that Django Test Client does not set the user in the request and it is not possible to set `request.user` while using `Client` any other way. I used `RequestFactory` to that.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.request_factory = RequestFactory()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='javed', email='javed@javed.com', password='my_secret')
    
def test_my_test_method(self):
    payload = {
        'question_title_name': 'my first question title',
        'question_name': 'my first question',
        'question_tag_name': 'first, question'
    }
    request = self.request_factory.post(reverse('home'), payload)
    request.user = self.user
    response = home_page(request)
```

More about request factory [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory)

Comment: I think it's better to use a setUpTestData as @classmethod for user creation, so we can use it in all other functions in that TestClass.

Comment: "it is not possible to set request.user while using Client any other way" was significant help. While OP is using a model backend, not all authentication backends assume a user stored in a DB (e.g. SSO via OIDC), so seeding the test data can be insufficient.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class YourTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_profile(self, user_id):
        user = User.objects.create(username='testuser')
        user.set_password('12345')
        user.save()
        client = Client()
        client.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
        response = client.get("/account/profile/{}/".format(user.id), follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Here, I first create the user and set the login credentials for the user. Then I create a client and login with that user. So in your views.py, when you do `request.user`, you will get this user.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)
```

Comment: Perhaps the method name changed at some point, I'm using force_login https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login

Comment: [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) is plain Django whereas DRF offers [`force_authenticate`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `django.test` you can do something like that:

```
self.client.force_login(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a response, you can access `response.context['user']`.

If you need a response object, just call any view that will create a context, e.g. `response = self.client.get('/')`.